# Submitting an HTML form with jQuery doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

**TL;DR:** I try to submit the form with jQuery but it doesn't work.

I need to do an ajax call when a user submits a form. The action of the form is outside my site, so I need to trap the form submission at this point before it's actually submitted.
This did work at some point, but now it doesn't, for some reason I can't figure out, I compared the commits before and after it stopped working and there was no code change so I don't know what it may be.
The form is a regular one, with POST method, an action, nothing strange.
Any ideas?

The idea is that when the user submits the form the submit handler prevents the regular submit and does the Ajax call.
When the AJAX call returns, the submit event is called again, this time the handler does nothing and doesn't prevent the regular submit, returns true, so it should submit the form to its action URL, but it doesn't happen.

```
<script>
var do_ajax_submit = true;

function manual_submit() {
    do_ajax_submit = false;
    $("form#lead_subscribe").submit();
}

$(function(){
    $("form#lead_subscribe").submit( function( ev )
    {
        var das = do_ajax_submit;
        if( do_ajax_submit )
        {
            do_ajax_submit = false;
            ev.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                url: "/someAjaxCall",
                method: "POST",
            })
            .always( function() {
                manual_submit();
            });
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What errors are you seeing in the console and have you observed the submission in the network tab?

Comment: Yes, no errors on the console and the submission doesn't happen on the network tab.

Comment: Is there a way to know why this question has been downvoted and voted to be closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear why the code should have worked, then stopped working.

One thing is for certain. By triggering form submission with the native `formNode.submit` instead of jQuery's `$("form#lead_subscribe").submit();`, the submission will not be re-intercepted by the event handler. Therefore the `do_ajax_submit` flag is unnecessary and the javascript cleans up significantly.

```
$(function() {
    $("form#lead_subscribe").on('submit', function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var formNode = this;
        $.ajax({
            url: "/someAjaxCall",
            method: "POST"
        })
        .always(function() {
            formNode.submit(); // native .submit() will not be re-intercepted by this submit handler.
        });
    });
});
```

There's a chance that this clean-up will also fix the problem. Hard to say.

Comment: Yes, this worked great. Thanks.
Why doesn't jQuery catch that submit() ?

Comment: This dates back years and years to the very early browsers. The idea is that javascript should be able to catch a form submission, do some verification, then either allow the form to submit of not, depending on how the verification went. In order to facilitate that, the `submit` event is not retransmitted when the form is submitted from POJS. Meanwhile, new kid-on-the-block, jQuery, doesn't follow the same rule; it's `$(form).submit()` *does* cause the `submit` event to be retransmitted. So it's not about  jQuery not catching; rather it is about suppression, or not, of the `submit` event.